# Open filenames stored in a list with a loop

Tags: r

I have a list of filenames to open. I need to open one file at a time, do some operations and then write the results to another file. How can I do this in R. In python I would do the same with

```
item = ['f1','f2','f3']
for stuff in item:
    f = open(stuff).read()
    #do some ops
    k = open('new/'+stuff,'w')
    k.write(f)
    k.close()
```

How can achieve the same in R. Is it something very similar?

Here's what I have done

```
fileList <- list.files("temp", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
filer<-function(filName){
csv4.data <- read.csv(paste('/home/amrith/ferosaRanks/combine/',filName,sep=""),header=FALSE)
mat = as.matrix(csv4.data)
(CESnoweights <- RankAggreg(mat, 14, method="CE", distance="Spearman", convIn=7, rho=.1))
write.csv(CESnoweights['top.list'],file=paste("/home/amrith/ferosaRanks/unW/",filName,sep=""))
}
lapply(fileList,filer)
```

Basically load filenames with list.files.
define the operations as a function
apply the operation to each entry with lapply

Comment: Yep, it is something very similar. `?"for"`, `?readLines`, `?writeLines` could help. With `?connection` and `?close` if you want to do something fancy (like set encoding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution if the files are in a csv format.

```
for (i in 1:length(item)){
   d <- read.csv(item[i])
   # do something to d
   new_file <- paste0(item[i], "_new")
   write.csv(d,file = new_file)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use paste(). For example, let's say I want to do stuff to all the files in a certain directory. First I can get the list with list.files().

```
filelist = list.files("C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/r")
```

Then I can use paste combined with read.csv to load the file (assuming you have csv's of course, but you can use this method in general.

```
df = read.csv(paste("C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/r/",filelist[1], sep = ""))
```

If all of your dataframes are the same, you can just use column numbers to do stuff.

```
df$newColumn = df[,1]+df[,2]
```

You can see how this could be done in a loop. You should also be able to see how you can do stuff to it.  For dynamic file names, you can still use this method. For example, say the original file is "XXX.csv" and you want your processed file to be "XXX processed.csv". Then after manipulating your data, you can do something like

```
write.csv(df, paste("C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/r/",filelist[1], " processed.csv", sep = ""), row.names = FALSE)
```

It's hard to be more specific without knowing exactly what your data looks like, but I think you get the idea.